# Regex for getting the number after the last delimeter of the line in Scala

Tags: regex, scala, parsing

My line is `889¦20457892¦955`

I want to get `955` as the output and this is my code but it gives `None` as the result

```
val pattern = "(^¦*)$\\d+".r
val str = "889¦20457892¦955"
println(pattern findFirstIn str)
```

Is this correct regex?

Comment: Try `val pattern = """(?<=¦)\d+$""".r`

Comment: Yeah it is working :) Even this works  val pattern = "([^¦]*)$".r what would be the difference between both ?

Comment: `[^¦]*$` matches 0 or more chars other than `¦`

Answer (score 5):

You may use

```
val pattern = """(?<=¦)\d+$""".r
val str = "889¦20457892¦955"
println(pattern findFirstIn str)
```

Here,

- `(?<=¦)` - location right after `¦`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Alternatively, you may just split with the `¦` char and get last item:

```
println(str.split('¦').last)
```

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/xdyjnQ)

Comment: Or just `"\\d+$".r`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribzew I am not able to process the record when there is a new line character at the end, Is there any changes required in the regex for that?
with the new line character the record will look like ths 889¦20457892¦955CRLF

Comment: @BARATH Yes, use `"""(?m)(?<=¦)\d+$""".r`. Or `"""(?m)(?<=¦)\d+(?=\r?$)""".r`

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `"\\d+$"` is enough to find the number at the end of a string.

```
val pattern = "\\d+$".r
val str = "889¦20457892¦955"
println(pattern findFirstIn str)
```

This works because the `+` operator in a regular expression is *greedy* and will collect all the characters that match the preceding expression. This means that there is no need to explicitly specify the delimiter.